# Android Countdown Error

Tags: java, android, countdown

I'm trying to make a simple countdown for my app that last 30 seconds, then ends the game, but as soon as the activity loads on my phone, the app crashes. Here is the code, and yes I am sure that it is my countdown code crashing the app.

```
public void UpdateTime()
{
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 100)
    {


        public void onTick(long l)
        {
          Time--;
          tDown.setText(Time);
        }


        public void onFinish()
        {
            GameOver();
        };
    }.start();
}
public void Begin()
{
   UpdateTime();

}
```

Comment: StackTrace please. why did your app crash.?

Comment: You should follow Java coding conventions: methods and variables start with a small cap (Time -> time, GameOver -> gameOver, UpdateTime -> updateTime...)

Comment: Hope you remember that 1 second = 1000 ms. So 30 seconds = 30000.  So your `CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 100)` would start 3 seconds countdown with 0.1 seconds tick period. Should not cause crash though, so as mentioned above - provide stack trace

Answer (score 4):

Other than the problems others have described, the real issue is that you are setting text like this:

```
tDown.setText(Time);
```

where Time is an integer. When you pass an integer to setText(), it looks for a String resource declared in strings.xml. What you really want is

```
tDown.setText(""+Time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see following typos in your code:

- extra semicolon
- explicit start() call

Also make sure your `tDown` variable is not `null` this can happen when Android could not find TextView with id you specified in `findViewById()` call

Try to modify your code like this:

```
public void UpdateTime()
{
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long l)
        {
            Time--;
            tDown.setText(Time);
        }


        public void onFinish()
        {
            GameOver();
        }
    }
    timer.start();
}
public void Begin()
{
   UpdateTime();
}
```